# Oracle11g large integer to hex string conversion in php

Tags: php, macos, oracle11g, biginteger

I have a column in table declared as `macaddr NUMBER(15)` (macaddress integer representation range - up to 15 digits)

The PHP fetch this values as a strings, obviously on 32bit system the `dechex` will not handle that big ints.

How I can easily convert that strings into hex macaddr representation (human redable)? And same question in opposite direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to store these informations in a numeric form? Modern computers have plenty of space available.

Anyway you can use PHP to convert numbers larger than that.
My humble solution is to avoid relying on types provided by PHP and use the *BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics*.
According to the manual the library comes bundled with PHP since release 4.0.4. If you run PHP in Windows it works straight. Otherwise you have to configure with **--enable-bcmath** .
Thanks to user contributed notes on the PHP.net website I found these two handy functions:

```
<?php

        /* hexadecimal to/from decimal functions from user contributed notes at http://it.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php */

        function bchexdec($hex) {
            if(strlen($hex) == 1) {
                return hexdec($hex);
            } else {
                $remain = substr($hex, 0, -1);
                $last = substr($hex, -1);
                return bcadd(bcmul(16, bchexdec($remain)), hexdec($last));
            }
        }

        function bcdechex($dec) {
            $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
            $remain = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);

            if($remain == 0) {
                return dechex($last);
            } else {
                return bcdechex($remain).dechex($last);
            }
        }

    echo bcdechex (130646634308);

    echo '<br />';

    echo bchexdec ('001e6b256f44');


    ?>
```

Comment: I need to store them as integers in db, because there will be numerous operations, like get next/previous mac number in pool, generating this from hex representation, will be error-prone, and with integers its just +/- operations

Answer (score 0):

You could find useful the *float* type, provided by PHP, which is large enough to hold your values. First convert into a float and then insert or update into your database field. The main problem here is to convert floats to/from hexadecimals.

After some work on my own trying to write a hex2dec function I came up with *the* resource: the PHP manual.

Take a look at the first comment, by **Nstiac**. He writes a couple of functions to convert Hex strings to Floating point numbers

**EDIT: The functions provided revealed to be broken somehow (see comments below)! Use at your risk!**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Not quite right...
Mac: `00:1E:6B:25:6F:44` has an int representation: `130646634308`, function provided in that comments produces: `float2hex32n('130646634308') = '4effffff'`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try the code before posting. I will edit my reply and look for another solution. Sorry again.